# Matplotlib - Can we drag two curves independently?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

Is it possible to move/drag two curves from different Y axes independently in a Matplotlib graph ? At the moment, when I move, zoom or drag these curves, both a moving at the same time. For instance, on the graph below, if I drag the blue curve up, I would like the red one to stay at the exact same position.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8621.png)
I know that Matlab allows two fully independent zoom levels for instance. Is it possible with Matplotlib as well ?

I have been searching the web and this forum but couldn't find an solution.

Comment: why do you need it? As for me it seems strange idea, and even useless idea - so I expect that matplot may not have this function because nobody needed this before.